# How do I strip out ?_escaped_fragment_= using .htaccess

Tags: ajax, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo

Google discovered that I'm allowing end users to navigate my content using ajax loading, and is loading my pages as a user client rather than requesting them as new page loads. So instead of trying to index www.mysite.com/page, it's requesting www.mysite.com/?_escaped_fragment_=/page

Which is not at all what I want it to do. My snapshots are served at the same URL as the ajax-loaded content. The site is not using queries, it's not supporting them and I don't want to build that support. This means that all the pages look broken to google which of course is unfortunate!

Currently all page requests are redirected server side using .htaccess sending requests to the index.php file which in turn compiles the html doc on the server before serving to the client. The site serves perfectly valid and unique html documents for all pages. But google insists on doing it the ajax way and adding the query which always returns a broken page.

I'm not a .htaccess expert, but it seems to me that the easiest way to solve this would be to rewrite the request, remove the ?_escaped_fragment_=/ bit and permanently redirect any such requests to what currently works which is to load the pages using their correct url's.

Anyone know how I would go about doing that? Below is the current redirect part of my .htaccess file which needs to be amended with the _escaped_fragment_ stripping code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on 
  RewriteBase /

  #if trailing / remove it with a permanent redirect
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

  #if missing www. add it with a permanent redirect
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301] 

  #requests for index.php never rewritten
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

  #if file or directory are missing, route to index.php
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Related [webmasters Q&A](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/41141/google-indexed-my-escaped-fragment-pages).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I rewrote it so that all ?_escaped_fragment_=/XXXXX requests got redirected to /XXXXX without the query

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%1? [L,R=301]
```

This makes www.domain.com/?_escaped_fragment_=/somepage redirect (permanently) to www.domain.com/somepage

...which is just what I wanted.